# DAX hasonevalue but also total

Tags: filter, dax

I have at table where I show a calcutated measure, but in the visulization I only want to show the measures if a specific dimension is in the filter.

This works great with HASONEVALUE:

Dividedmeasure:= IF(HASONEVALUE('Employment'[EmploymentGroup]), DIVIDE([measure1)], [Measure2],(BLANK() )))

The problem is HASONEVALUE also blanks the total which Is not what I want. I want to blank everything where EmploymentGroup is not in the filters since the report doens't make sense without Employmentgroup. Any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P7IC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I think You should remove BLANK(). Then It won't show anything where [EmploymentGroup] is not inside the filter.

1st Method: HASONEFILTER()

```
Dividedmeasure =
IF (
    HASONEFILTER ( 'Employment'[EmploymentGroup] ),
    DIVIDE ( [measure1], [Measure2] ),
)
```

2nd Method: ISFILTERED()

```
Dividedmeasure =
IF (
    ISFILTERED ( 'Employment'[EmploymentGroup] ),
    DIVIDE ( [measure1], [Measure2] )
)
```